# Min Max Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Return a list with two items in it, the minimum and maximum from the list passed into the function. The minimum should be first in the list and the maximum second.

If the list passed in is empty, the min and max are just zero.

Examples:

```
min_max([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) returns [1, 6]

min_max([43, 12, 0, 372, 1, -5]) returns [-5, 372]

min_max([]) returns [0, 0]
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: Hi welsome on Stackoverflow. SO is not a code-writing service. You must post your code and explain the problem you are facing for us to help/guide you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider not utilizing the inbuilt [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) functions for a one-pass solution:

```
from typing import Sequence


def min_max(seq: Sequence[int]) -> list[int]:
    if not seq:
        return [0, 0]
    minimum, maximum = float('inf'), float('-inf')
    for val in seq:
        if val < minimum:
            minimum = val
        if val > maximum:
            maximum = val
    return [minimum, maximum]


def main() -> None:
    print(f'min_max([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) = {min_max([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])}')
    print(f'min_max([43, 12, 0, 372, 1, -5]) = {min_max([43, 12, 0, 372, 1, -5])}')
    print(f'min_max([]) = {min_max([])}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
min_max([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) = [1, 6]
min_max([43, 12, 0, 372, 1, -5]) = [-5, 372]
min_max([]) = [0, 0]
```